# How to loop with R string Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Currently, my code is like this:

```
for images in range(500):
    image = cv2.imread(r'C:\\mypath\images.png')
```

How can I loop through? I tried using {}.format(images) but that doesn't work with r strings?

edit: updated code problem

```
for i in range(500):
    image = cv2.imread(fr'mypath\captcha{i}.png')
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow('Binary image', thresh)
    cv2.imwrite(fr'mypath\captcha{i}.png', thresh)
```

error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: What's the outcome you expect? For now I see a `for ` loop that iterate from `0` to `499`. How do you plan to use this. Or do you want to read all images from a specific path?

Comment: I have images in a folder named 0.png, 1.png, ... , 499.png. I want to loop through all these images and do something to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use f-strings ?

```
for images in range(500):
    image = cv2.imread(f'C:\\mypath\{images}.png')
```

If r-strings are needed, then just use fr-strings, e.g.:

```
for images in range(500):
    image = cv2.imread(fr'C:\\mypath\{images}.png')
```

You might need to change \ to / as well. Sometimes it's necessary.

Comment: because I have to use r string for imread function

Comment: still doesnt work with fr string, please see updated code

Comment: sorry, this works, checked my source folder, I 2.png was not there so the code failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for images in range(500):
    image = cv2.imread(r'C:\\mypath\{}.png'.format(images))
```

This will do. I think you used it wrong. Or maybe you can add the error you're getting using it like this, as you said it didnn't work for you

Comment: i am getting the error: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'. When hardcode the path to 0.png and run the code, it works.

Comment: maybe you can try `image = cv2.imread(r'C:\\mypath\{}.png'.format(str(images)))`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Please post this error you're getting in the question. Maybe someone knows how to solve it. I really don't have any idea what that error can be

Comment: please see my edit in the question, updated code